# Run rvm/ruby as new user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, installation, rvm

I'm completely new to Ruby and I've completely botched the download with rvm. I'm throwing errors left and right.

Is there a way to start the install over and do a 100% clean install? Can I start over by creating a new user account?

I'm completely stuck here!

Answer (score 0):

```
rvm implode
```

or

remove the rvm folder manually (~/.rvm) and remove the rvm line in your .bashrc file

Answer (score 0):

you should not remove `rvm`, you should read the error messages, if the messages do not tell you what is wrong / what to fix you have three ways of getting help(ordered by response time):

- connect to irc `#rvm`: http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=rvm
- open a ticket for rvm: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues
- ask for help in rvm mailing list: https://groups.google.com/group/rubyversionmanager